# Is it worth getting a clean error log on production site?

Tags: php, apache

2 days ago we switched in our office from PHP 5.2.x to 5.3.x and it caused some problems at first, but we managed to fix 'em pretty fast.

Since lots of bugfixes were done by looking at error logs, something popped up in my mind.

Well, there are all these `PHP Notices` about undefined variables and other, as I consider, not urgent, messages. I did reconfigure one of my recent projects, to stop showing these notices, but then there is a question... **Is it considered good practice, to not log notices and only look for *real* errors? And why?**

I'm kind of confused at the moment, because we have more than enough running sites at the moment, and I have no idea — should I leave those sites alone, or should I reconfigure them to log only *really bad stuff*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's good practice to not generate notices in the first place, since they're a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: Code smell is a good one, yeah! ^^, And yes, with logging I meant generating 'em. Basicly, "notices" is one of those things which should be disabled by default on production site?

Comment: Logging and generating are two different things. It is possible to generate a notice even if it is not logged.

Comment: @Tom, there are two schools of thought about that. Notices should certainly be enabled in Development, but the biggest reason they should be disabled in Production is because too many developers have them turned off... :-/

Comment: Notices are debug messages. And it's not a good idea to suppress them with huge piles of isset decorations. Applied inconsiderate it might hide actual pitfalls.

Answer (score 2):

We have notices running on our pre-production environments so we can detect any potential errors or bad practices before we release to production. On production, we only log the bad stuff.

Comment: And you're considering 'undefined variables' as a bad practice? Should I avoid those (start defining them)? I'm working on a new website system at the moment, therefore interested in any information.

Comment: Yes! You should not use any undefined variables. PHP has a reliable check to see if a variable is undefined or not.

Comment: Seriously, Tom, are there people consciously writing code with undefined variables? ick

Comment: @Andrew, well, looks like there are. But that means I have to define empty variables in every function? Seems like a bit of an overkill.

Comment: @Tom - I felt that way for a while, and then one day I had to go back and edit a 300+ line `"we need it done yesterday"` slapdash disaster function and seeing variables appear out of nowhere, even with the IDE's helpful highlighting, was an irritating experience... and I only had myself to blame! `/shakes fist at mirror` So yeah, I define everything now.